# Local storage limit for each domain or for all domains?

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I'm doing a lot of projects using local storage.

- Some live on the desktop: C:/Users/[myName]Desktop/...
- Some use the VS Code server: http://127.0.0.1:5500/index.html
- Others are on Git Pages.

Depending on which post you read, Chrome has a local storage limit of 5MB.

Does this mean that ALL the domains listed above share one limit of 5MB, or
do they have 5MB each?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each domain (e.g. "http://127.0.0.1:5500" and "https://[username].github.io") has its own separate limit of 5MB for local storage in Chrome. This means that if you have two separate websites running on different domains, each will have its own 5MB limit for local storage.

Answer (score 2):

Every domain has its own localStorage instance which means each domain/sub-domain/protocol have its own limit of 5 MB storage.

One domain can't share its localStorage space with another domain.

Comment: That cleared it up :)